# Опеределение числа тайлов до темпай в риичи-маджонге

Tags: алгоритм

Существует такая игра - риичи-маджонг ([правила](http://tesuji-club.ru/osnovi-pravil-riichi/)). Цель игры: быстрее всех собрать из имеющегося набора тайлов (три масти числовых тайлов от 1 до 9, четыре типа ветров по сторонам света, три типа драконов, каждого тайла в наборе по четыре штуки) собрать четыре сета и пару (с определёнными оговорками). 
Типы тайлов:

[image: "ман": 1-9]

[image: "пин": 1-9]

[image: "соу": 1-9]

[image: ветра: север, восток, юг, запад]

[image: драконы: белый, зелёный, красный]

Сет - три или четыре любых одинаковых тайла (1-1-1) или же последовательность из трёх идущих подряд числовых тайлов типа 1-2-3. Всего в готовой руке 14 тайлов. Четыре сета по 3 тайла (12) плюс два тайла в пару (2). У игрока 14 тайлов только в о время своего хода (взял тайл, посмотрел, выкинул ненужный), в остальное время их 13.

Есть такое понятие в игре: темпай, когда до готовой руки остайтся один тайл, который завершал бы один из сетов или пару.
И есть ещё одно понятие: шантен, которое обозначает минимальное количество замен тайлов, чтобы оказаться в состоянии темпая. Примеры в одной масти:

- 1-1-1, 3-3-3, 5-5-5, 8-8-8, 9-9 -
  пример готовой руки
- 1-1, 3-3-3, 5-5-5, 8-8-8, 9-9 - темпай,
  нужен тайл для победы. В данном
  случае это 1 или 9.
- х, 1-1, 3-3, 5-5-5, 8-8-8, 9-9 - 1-шантен, 1 тайл
  до темпай, если придёт 1, 3 или 9, то
  до победы останется 1 тайл.
- 1-2-3, 2-3, 8-8-8, 9-9-9, 6-6 - 1-шантен, есть сеты из последовательностей,
  темпай при приходе 1, 4, 6. И так далее.

Как можно рассчитать число шантен? Есть ли литература по чему-то подобному? 
Сложность в том, что комбинации численных тайлов могут быть непростые и надо как-то среди мешанины близких тайлов углядеть комбинации. Или когда в руке просто ерунда всякая и на сеты одни только намёки: 5-7, 1-2, 9-9, да ещё и в разных мастях.

*Зачем это надо: это число может использоваться ботом как критерий выбора тайла для сброса, например. Так же, это может помочь определить победное ожидание при темпае.*

Comment: Рыть скорее всего прийдется в сторону теории графов. Готовых алгоритмов скорее всего не будет, посмотрите конечно что-нибудь про игру в кости или блек-джек)) но все равно прийдется переделывать.

Думаю нужен будет набор кончных автоматов, которые будут подбирать сеты разных типов и "недосеты", которые будут запускаться в разном порядке для разных типов (то есть прогонятся будут все, но начинать будет каждый раз с другого). В результате этого будет таблица возможных группировок фишек. Из которой нужно выбрать самые оптимистичные варианты. Желательно учитывать вероятности, то есть

Comment: если у вас уже выпали фишки 1-2-3 и 3-3, то ждать ещё одну 3 для двух сетов смысла практически нет, так как их всего четыре.

Я бы вам посоветовал подкинуть данный вопрос на форуме математиков - они такое любят)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239028/how-do-i-calculate-the-shanten-number-in-mahjong. Минусы: автор пишет что эвристика работает не всегда (т.к. она построена на правилах, которые обычно, но не всегда верны), плюс оно, похоже, явно ничего не знает про яку.

Comment: drdaeman, для шантена яку не играет никакой роли =) Выиграть же можно и по особой ситуации, которая даст соответствующее яку, или по риичи.

Но надо вчитаться в ту тему, может, придумается что =)

Comment: Нашёл два файла с кодом:
http://cmj3.web.fc2.com/syanten.h
http://cmj3.web.fc2.com/syanten.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи необходим рекурсивный алгоритм обхода руки. Вырезая формы из руки во всех возможных вариантах и подсчитывая их число, по формуле

Shanten = Min(Shanten, 8 - <колво сетов> * 2 - <колво неготовых форм> - <количество пар>)

Единственное, что формы пропускаются, когда их количество (сетов+форм) становится больше четырёх. Так как сетов надо всего четыре, лишние формы ничего не дают.

Описано: [Расчёт числа шантен](http://teplofizik.diary.ru/p185152268.htm).